# A construction of a Stratonovich type integral for fractional Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

I'm studying this article https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.twjm/1500574954 and I'm having problems understanding the proof of lemma 3.

Let me recall some of the criminals involved. Let $(u_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be a simple bounded process of the form

$$
u = \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1} F_j 1_{(t_s, t_{j+1}]},
$$
let us define
$$ 
u^\epsilon_t = \frac{1}{2 \epsilon}\int_{t - \epsilon}^{t+\epsilon} u_r \ dr.
$$
Let us define the seminorm
$$
\lvert| \phi |\rvert_K^2 = \int_0^T \phi(s)^2 K(T,s)^2 \ ds + \int_0^T \left(\int_s^T \left | \phi(t) - \phi(s) \right | (t-s)^{H - \frac{3}{2}} \ dt \right)^2 \ ds
$$
where $K$ satisfies
$$ \left | K(t,s) \right  | \leq c((t-s)^{H - \frac{1}{2}} + s^{H - \frac{1}{2}}) $$ and 
$$\left | \frac{\partial K}{\partial t} (t,s) \right | \leq c (t-s)^{H - \frac{3}{2}}$$
where $H < \frac{1}{2}$. Let $\mathcal{H}_K$ be the completion of the set of step functions with respect to the norm defined above. Then at page 614 it is stated that $u_t^\epsilon$ converges to $u$ in $\mathbb{D}^{1,2}(\mathcal{H}_K)$. The key step that I'm missing is the integral estimate done at page 615, in fact I obtain and estimate that also involves the integral: 
$$
\int_{t_i + 2 \epsilon}^{t_{i+1} - 2 \epsilon} \left( \int_{s}^{t_i + 2 \epsilon} \left| u_t^\epsilon - u_s^\epsilon \right | (t-s)^{H - \frac{3}{2}} \ dt \right)^2 \ ds
$$
and I am not able to state that this integral converges to zero. Any suggestions?

Comment: Regarding the last integral, don't we have $|u_t^\epsilon-u_s^\epsilon|=0$ for $s,t\in(t_i+2\epsilon,t_{i+1}-2\epsilon)$?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Anyway in the integral $\int_s^{t_i + 2 \epsilon} \dots$, $s$ belongs to $[0, t_i + 2 \epsilon]$ and that shall not be null.

Comment: I meant $t$ not $s$.

Comment: ? In the inner integral, $t$ lies between $s$ and $t_i+2\epsilon$ while $s$ lies between $t_i+2\epsilon$ and $t_{i+1}-2\epsilon$, so $t$, too, lies between $t_i+2\epsilon$ and $t_{i+1}-2\epsilon$. Where does $0$ in $[0,t_i+2\epsilon]$ come from?

Comment: You're right, stupidly I didn't notice it.